# Move comma position JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to move the position of the comma with the use of JavaScript. I have managed to remove all the parts of the string I needed removing. The only problem is that the comma is in the wrong position.

The current outcome is `425.00`, but I simply want '42.50'

```
success: function(result) {
   if (result != '') {
      alert(" "+result+" ");
   }

   var discountVal = result.replace(/\D/g,'');
   newDiscountVal = discountVal.replace(7.50, '');
   $("input#amount").val(discountVal);
}
```

I am grabbing database echo values with a combination of string and echo - numbers..

Comment: Why not divide by 10?

Comment: You want to move comma or decimal?

Comment: want the comma to simply move back 2 or maybe i could change the size of the decimal places?

Comment: is there an example instead of just telling me what to do?

Comment: It sounds like you're making a problem where there shouldn't be one. What's the issue with dividing by 10?

Comment: And Kilter didn't tell you what to do. It was merely posed as a (very reasonable) question.

Comment: i have my values, i just want the comma in the right place..

Comment: The current outcome that is stored in database is **4250.00**, but I simply want 42.50.

Comment: I have values originally stored in a database, the replace works fine but the values that are returning have no commas, so the database thinks the the total is **4250.00** when it should be **42.50** in other words 42 pound and 50 pence..

Comment: mate you dont read what im after, i just simply want a comma in the right place... **i want the comma to be 2 decimal places in** from the front...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could divide by ten, then convert back to a String using toFixed(2) which forces formatting of 2 decimal places

Javascript allows implicit conversion of Strings to numbers, by firstly converting the String to a Number so it is valid to divide a String by a number.

```
var input= "4250.00";
var output = (original / 100).toFixed(2); // => "42.50"
```

Note this method has different behaviour due to rounding. Consider the case 9.99. If you use a string manipulation technique you'll get ".99", with divide by 10 method above you'll get "1.00". However from what has been said in comments I believe your inputs always end .00 and never anything else, so there will be no difference in reality.

Comment: why list an original value ? surely that wont work if there are multiple returned values?

Comment: "original" variable is just an example to make my snippet self contained

Comment: yeah divide is useless.

Answer (score 1):

If it is number you can just divide by 10

If it is string you can do like this:

```
var ind = text.indexOf('.');
text = text.replace('.', '');
text.slice(0, ind-1) + '.' + text.slice(ind-1, text.length)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution:

```
function moveComma(val, moveCommaByInput) {
  if (val || typeof val === 'number') {
    const valueNumber = Number(val);
    const moveCommaBy = moveCommaByInput || 0;

    if (isNaN(valueNumber)) {
      return null;
    } else {
      return Number(`${valueNumber}e${moveCommaBy}`);
    }
  }

  return null;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is how i solved it..

```
                      var discountVal = result.replace(/\D/g, '');
                      var newDiscountVal = discountVal.replace(7.50, '');
                      var lastDigits = newDiscountVal.substr(newDiscountVal.length - 2);
                      var removedDigits = newDiscountVal.slice(0,newDiscountVal.length - 2);
                      var discountRealValue = removedDigits + '.' + lastDigits;
                      $("input#amount").val(discountRealValue);
```

Cheers